# Firebase function for emulator, ignore on deploy

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm looking for a way to exclude some firebase functions, when I run `firebase deploy`. But I want to keep these functions, when I'm running the emulator.

When I execute my integration tests with flutter driver, and my app being connected to the emulator, I need some way to change the data in firestore from my test-script. A firebase function, which I can call using the http package would be a nice way to do that. But these emulator specific functions must not be deployed to production. I know I can use the `--only` flag, when I run `firebase deploy` to specify all the functions, I want to deploy. But this is kind of cumbersome. I don't want to write down all the names of the functions I want to deploy, every time.

I'm aware of the fact, that the functions-key in my firebase.json can be used with an "ignore" field. But I can't figure out how that works. All the functions which are export in the src/index.ts file (gets compiled to lib/src/index.js) are deployed. So how does the ignore-key work? I tried to use it like this:

```
{
    "functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "ignore": [
        "**/node_modules/**",
      "**/src/emulator/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

But that results in a Deployment error.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to my problem. By putting this into my index.ts

```
var emulator = undefined;
if(process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR) {
    emulator = emulatorFunction;
}

export {emulator};
```

the functions I use with the emulator do not get deployed to production, when I run `firebase deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

The `functions.ignore` property is [undocumented](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1602#issuecomment-521761044), but works in the same way as the hosting.ignore property. It defaults to `['node_modules', '.git']`, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/127ca3fbf7549d6c0cdf12e89e4465de9dd2b7c9/src/deploy/functions/prepareFunctionsUpload.ts#L71).

It *should* accept glob-like patterns similar to a .gitignore.